# Scala: how to implement Java class with more constructors

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

I have searched for hours, but I did not found a solution:

I want to implement a Scala class that extends a Java class that has different constructors:

The Java class (JGoodies):

```
public abstract class AbstractTableAdapter<E> 
    extends AbstractTableModel implements ListModelBindable
```

The constructors:

```
AbstractTableAdapter()
AbstractTableAdapter(ListModel listModel)
AbstractTableAdapter(String... columnNames)
AbstractTableAdapter(ListModel listModel, String... columnNames)
```

The ListModel is a generic interface if that matters:

```
public interface ListModel<E>
```

I tried in Scala 2.11:

```
class LibraryListTableModel(listModel: SelectionInList[Book], columnNames: Array[String]) extends AbstractTableAdapter[Book](listModel, columnNames) {
    def this() = this(null, null)
    def this(listModel: SelectionInList[Book]) = this(null, null)
    def this(columnNames: Array[String]) = this(null, null)
}
```

but that gives this error message:

```
error: overloaded method constructor AbstractTableAdapter with alternatives:
[INFO]   (x$1: javax.swing.ListModel[_],x$2: String*)com.jgoodies.binding.adapter.AbstractTableAdapter[eu.eyan.idakonyvtar.model.Book] <and>
[INFO]   (x$1: String*)com.jgoodies.binding.adapter.AbstractTableAdapter[eu.eyan.idakonyvtar.model.Book]
[INFO]  cannot be applied to (com.jgoodies.binding.list.SelectionInList[eu.eyan.idakonyvtar.model.Book], Array[String])
[INFO]     extends AbstractTableAdapter[Book](listModel, columnNames) {
[INFO]             ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

I think the `String...` causes the problem..
Is it possible to extend such an abstract class?
Thanks:
András

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can destructure in the incoming array into its various elements for the vararg by using the `: _*` syntax, i.e.:

```
case class Base(strs: String*) {  }
class Sub(ary: Array[String]) extends Base(ary:_*) { }
```

EDIT: Note, that `WrappedArray` (the result of the vararg) extends `ArrayLike` but I don't believe it's an `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was indeed marking the String... parameter with :_*

```
class LibraryListTableModel(listModel: SelectionInList[Book], columnNames: String*) extends AbstractTableAdapter[Book](listModel, columnNames: _*) {...}
```

This post helped too:
http://daily-scala.blogspot.de/2009/11/varargs.html